# Visual Studio 2019で作成したコンソールアプリをdllとexeに分けないで、1つのファイル(exe)として出力したい

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

C#で開発をしているのですが、exeとdllを1つにまとめる方法として、[ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge)があるようですが、その方法は古く、Visual Studio 2019だけでもできると思うのですが、うまくいきません。

Microsoft Q&Aでそれっぽいのを見つけたのですが、うまくいきません。

[Build a stand-alone executable by Visual Studio 2019 Community](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/178986/build-a-stand-alone-executable-by-visual-studio-20.html)

### 行った方法

1. プロジェクトを選択
2. 右クリックし、`発行(B)`を選択
3. `すべての設定を表示`を選択
4. 配置モードを`自己完結`に変更
5. `ファイルの公開オプション`を選択
6. `単一ファイルを作成`にチェックマークを入れる
7. `発行`ボタンを選択

これで実行されますが、exeとdllは別々のファイルになってしまい、exeファイルだけでは実行できません。

### 環境

- Visual Studio 2019
- C#
- .Net 5.0

Comment: こちらの記事とかが参考になるのでは？ [単一ファイルの配置と実行可能ファイル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file)

Comment: 言語は何でしょう C / C++ / C# できれば質問本文に追記お願いします

Comment: これに類似する作業をdllについて行う必要があるのかも？ [サードパーティの依存関係を含む、自己完結型の展開](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs157#self-contained-deployment-with-third-party-dependencies) 他にこんな記事がありました。[.NET 5でシングルバイナリを作る](https://opcdiary.net/net-5%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B/) `WindowsでEXE1本にどうしてもまとめたい場合にはコマンドラインから操作する以外に方法はないようです。`

Comment: 参照された手順には「If it is .net core」とありますが、該当していますか？ 環境情報を記載してください。

Comment: 環境情報を追記しました。[@kunif](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26370/kunif)さんに載せていただいた記事でうまくいきました!うまくいかない原因は`IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract`の設定不足だったようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントで教えてくださった方法で、解決できましたので、載せておきます。
出来なかった原因としては、プロジェクトの設定で`IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract`を`true`にしていなかったことでした。

`.csproj`ファイル内の`<PeroperyGroup>`内に`<IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>`の記述を追加することで、exeファイルのみで実行できるexeファイルが出力できました。(`.pdb`というデバッグ用のファイルも生成されましたが、削除してもexeには影響はなかったです。(`.pdb`を生成しない設定を見つけたので、下のコメントに載せておきます)

さらに日本語の記事も見つけたので、載せておきます。
[.NET 5でシングルバイナリを作る](https://opcdiary.net/net-5%E3%81%A7%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AB%E3%83%90%E3%82%A4%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B/)

Comment: 問題点としては`.csproj`を自分で編集しなくては行けなくて、GUIでの編集のしかたがわかりません。(ないのかも?)
もしわかる方がいたら教えてください。

Comment: .pbdを生成しない方法
プロジェクトのプロパティ->ビルド->構成をReleaseに変更->詳細->`デバッグ情報`を`なし`へ変更